# Debugging ASP.net reporting services website memory leak?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, reporting-services

We have an ASP.net website built in C#/VB built on reporting services. Some of these are local (rdlc) and some sit on a reporting server (rdl).

The problem we are running into is that about every two weeks the server starts reporting OOM errors and the IIS worker process is running away with memory. The quick fix seems to be restarting iis, but this requires manual interaction and is usually reported by users.

It seems like a memory leak somewhere, but most of the reports are really simple data pulls and connections are all closed, at this point we don't really know how to debug it further.

Any ideas?

Comment: I sympathize, but feel the question is a bit too vague for Stack Overflow. Can you be more specific about what you would like to debug?

Comment: so for example. I have two different reports on the same reporting server. both hit different tables and stored procedures in the database. After a while the web server starts to get maxed out and I get OOM errors. Since there is no load on the database how do I tell which report is causing it? 

In a test environment I would separate the two reports onto different report servers to test, but this isn't valid for a production environment and it doesn't fail on our QA servers...

Comment: If you don't have any specific leads to debug this, you can always resort to [binary search debugging](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/50552/how-to-effectively-do-manual-debugging/181223#181223) to track down the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can run the IIS Debug Diagnostic Tool to see what the offending handle is http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919789